# Node.js http.get 404 kills the app

Tags: node.js, http, get, kill

I successfully wrote app in node.js working with http.get. Problem is, that if page doesn't exist, it make an error that terminates the app. Is any way how to declare timeout. After timeout it should stop waiting for response and let app continue (if written synchronously)
Thanks for all advices...

Comment: handle the error by giving `.on('error', function(e){});` See http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

Answer (score 0):

I'm responding thinking that you are trying to retrieve info via http.get.

1. You can see the validate using the response status code.

   ```
   http.get(url, function(res) {
       if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
           Your custom handler
       } else {
           var body = '';

           res.on('data', function(chunk) {
               body += chunk;
           });

           res.on('end', function() {
               console.log(body);
           });
       }
   }).on('error', function(e) {
   console.log("error: ", e);
   });
   ```

   A fully implemented example can be found her https://gist.github.com/pasupulaphani/9630789
2. You can set timeout and emit an error/abort if the request takes too long but this has to be done in application logic.

   Found a better/sophisticated solution to handle timeouts in other post :
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/12815321/2073176